# ActiveFormat returning wrong ISO values

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Having a problem getting camera to work properly.

I can take a video, and edit properties (ISO, focus) of the video in real time. But 'activeFormat.min/maxISO' returns incorrect values for reasons I don't understand.

For example: activeformat.maxISO returns 3264, while the camera crashes if I try to set the ISO higher than 1400. Pic: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8WPd.png (not enough rep to post pic directly)

Does anyone know why these calls return incorrect values?

Comment: Try using the AVCaptureISOCurrent as iso and see what happens. In general "This method throws an exception if you set the exposure duration or ISO values to an unsupported level": https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/1624646-setexposuremodecustom

Answer (score 0):

The 'answer' is here is to stop formatting the camera incorrectly.
Do not use bindings inside the camera.
I made a reddit post where I described this more:  https://www.reddit.com/r/SwiftUI/comments/v8n4hv/activeformat_returning_wrong_iso_values/